# Horizontal scrolling not working when position absolute/fixed

Tags: css

I have a horizontal scrollbar containing images:

```
<ion-view class="menu-content" view-title="Filter">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
        <div class="filter-examples">
            <img class="filter-examples-img" ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-src="{{filter.image}}" />
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

With the following css the scrolling is working really good:

```
.filter-examples {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.filter-examples-img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

The problem is it is sticked at the top. I want it to be at the bottom so i tried this:

```
.filter-examples {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Now it is sticked to the bottom of the page but the horizontal scrolling is not working anymore. How can i stick it to the bottom without disabeling the scrolling?

**ADD**

A [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYPgyr)

Comment: If you need it always at the bottom of the page, you should use position:fixed.
**.filter-examples { position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0}** That;s it.

Comment: position: fixed also disables the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: here you got a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYPgyr
remove the position fixed to see the scrolling

Comment: In Your codepen You provide `.wide-as-needed` class... Add `width:100%;` and You'll get horiz.scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by adding width 100% to your image container

```
.wide-as-needed {
  ...
  width:100%;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVYqwm